# Match `json` response with string

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, retrofit2

On click of selected date, I want to display related tasks or events.

```
public static List<ScheduledTasks> getResponse() {
   String res = "[{\n" +
                "\t\"scheduleId\": \"999\",\n" +
                "\t\"eventType\": \"first\",\n" +
                "\t\"impacts\": \"high\",\n" +
                "\t\"startDate\": 27032018,\n" +
                "\t\"endDate\": 27032018,\n" +
                "\t\"machineOwner\": \"Nilesh\",\n" +
                "\t\"description\": \"good\",\n" +
                "\t\"status\": \"working\"\n" +
                "}, ...
                "}]";


        return new Gson().fromJson(res, new TypeToken<List<ScheduledTasks>>(){}.getType());
```

this is the JSON.

Using the below

```
  LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("dateselected");
    ScheduledTasks=getResponse();
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(ScheduledTasks);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    List<ScheduledTasks>
```

I want to display only tasks for selected date.
String S date needs to be matched with json response and show particular tasks.
for date 27 only the tasks on that day should be displated.

Comment: i guess you need to parse this than only you can get desired output

Comment: filter your `ScheduledTasks` before or after you setthem to Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your getResponse method a bit like this so you can filter by date

```
 public static List<ScheduledTasks> getResponse(String dateselected) {
    String res = "[{\n" +
            "\t\"scheduleId\": \"999\",\n" +
            "\t\"eventType\": \"first\",\n" +
            "\t\"impacts\": \"high\",\n" +
            "\t\"startDate\": 27032018,\n" +
            "\t\"endDate\": 27032018,\n" +
            "\t\"machineOwner\": \"Nilesh\",\n" +
            "\t\"description\": \"good\",\n" +
            "\t\"status\": \"working\"\n" +
            "}, ...
    "}]";
    JSONArray array= null;
    JSONArray filter=new JSONArray();
    try {
        //change res to a JsonArray object so i can filter
        array = new JSONArray(res);
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<array.length();i++){
                String date=array.getJSONObject(i).has("startDate")?array.getJSONObject(i).getString("startDate"):"";
                //if i match selected date i pick it
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(date)&&date.equals(dateselected))
                    filter.put(array.getJSONObject(i));
            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  //res 
    res=filter.toString();

    return new Gson().fromJson(res, new TypeToken<List<ScheduledTasks>>() {
    }.getType());
}
```